# client side event tracking on intention or success?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, client-side, event-tracking

I have a conceptual issue regarding tracking user behavior on websites and analytics.

Should one track intention or completion?

What I mean by that is: If I have a button triggering an ajax call, for example, should I track that the user clicked the login button or that the login was successful?

Answer (score 0):

Most clients I have worked with have only been interested in tracking *successful* logins. However, I've had plenty of clients that also track if the visitor fails to login (and sometimes what the failure was). And even some who track the initial click itself, usually putting it into a general "Site Interaction" bucket where they pretty much track any click on their site.

However, one thing I always tell my clients about tracking stuff.. being able to look at data from user activity on your site can be fun and interesting from a "trivia" perspective. It's like knowing a lot of random movie facts or pop culture references from the 80's.

But from a *business* perspective, tracking an activity on a site is pointless (and a waste of money/resources) if you can't or aren't going to actually do anything with that information. The root goal of any business is to make more money, and "best practice" for any business is to not do anything that isn't helping make money.

So, the question you have to ask yourself is: "How can this data help me make business decisions?" If you cannot think of any reason how it will help you make business decisions, then don't track it.